# Center element horizontally in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to center a button horizontally, this is my code:

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.root}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SafeAreaView style={HEADER}>
          <SliderBox
            style={{ height: '100%' }}
            currentImageEmitter={index => setCurrentSliderNumber(index)}
            images={data.images}>
          </SliderBox>
        </SafeAreaView>
        {currentSliderNumber == data.images.length - 1 ? <View style={styles.item}>
          <Button
            style={styles.getStartedButton}
            appearance="ghost"
            status="control"
            onPress={onGetStartedPressed}
          >
            Get Started
          </Button>
        </View> : null}
      </View>
    </View>
  )
```

and this is my styling:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  forgotPasswordButton: {
    paddingHorizontal: 0,
  },
  root: {
    flex: 1,
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  },
  container: {
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
  },
  getStartedButton: {
    marginVertical: 12,
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  item: {
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '80%',
    left: '50%'
  }, text: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '30%',
    left: '10%'
  }
})
```

I also tried to add `alingnItems:center` to `root`:

```
root: {
        flex: 1,
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }
```

But the result is not the one expected:

[image]

Comment: As long as you know `flex` and `position, left, right`, this is not a problem you can't solve. On the other hand if you DON'T know those AND you are developing React-Native, I suggest you go refresh your CSS 'skills'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the item style object to this:

```js
item: {
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '80%',
    left:0,
    width:"100%",
    alignItems:"center",
    justifyContent:"center"
  },
```

Comment: You mean     alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'? I tried but the button is then the button is on the left side

Comment: Yeah I was meaning `alignItems` and `justifyContent`. I just edited my answer. Give it a shot.

Comment: Adding the width fixed the problem, thank you

Comment: Glad it worked out !

Answer (score 0):

Do not use position until it's necessary you should use flex properties.

```
return (
    <View style={styles.root}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SafeAreaView style={HEADER}>
          <SliderBox
            style={{ height: '100%' }}
            currentImageEmitter={index => setCurrentSliderNumber(index)}
            images={data.images}>
          </SliderBox>
        </SafeAreaView>
        {currentSliderNumber == data.images.length - 1 ? <View style={styles.item}>
          <Button
            style={styles.getStartedButton}
            appearance="ghost"
            status="control"
            onPress={onGetStartedPressed}
          >
            Get Started
          </Button>
   

 </View> : null}
      </View>
    </View>
  )
```

Styles

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  forgotPasswordButton: {
    paddingHorizontal: 0,
  },
  root: {
    flex: 1,
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  },
  container: {
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
    flexGrow:1,
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  },
  getStartedButton: {
    marginVertical: 12,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    alignSelf:"center",
    flexGrow:2,
  },
  item: {
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
    flexGrow:1,
    justifyContent:"center",
    alignItem:"center",
  }, text: {
  }
})
```

Check out the [layout docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props)

Comment: The button disappears from the screen with this style

Comment: @user567 check now.

Comment: Still the same, no button

Comment: Sorry, Not sure about this then maybe you can create a expo snippet online and share link.